# Check if time of NSDate object has passed

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Im trying to check if the time of an NSDate has passed. Ive used the following but that obviously has the year so therefore it has passed. How would I check just the time of the NSDate object, only Hour and minutes are important:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:openingDay.endTime];

if ([date timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0) {

}
```

But the date is:

```
2000-01-01 5:30:00 p.m. +0000
```

The time string has the format 'HH:mm:ss'

I tried looking for the answer as I thought it would be common but no luck.

Edit:

I should have elaborated some more, I get a time from a server which is a string. I want to then check if this time is past. The string is an end time of a shops opening hours, I therefore want to check if the shop has closed.

Edit2:

the string I get from the Json object is end_time:17:30:00. I then want to check if the current time is after this time, if so, then show a closed UIAlertView. My approach was to take this string and turn it into a date object and compare it to the current time. However when I convert it to an NSDate object the year is 2000, which is obviously in the past. I hope I have provided enough.

Comment: Just parse the string into its components to get its hour and minutes. No need for date formatters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the hour and minutes component, you do this:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
```

You can then create helper methods to keep the code organized:

```
- (NSInteger)hourFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:(NSCalendarUnitHour) fromDate:date];
}

- (NSInteger)minuteFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:(NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
}
```

note that `component:fromDate:`returns directly that component (as `NSInteger`), since it can only take one component type per parameter, while `components:fromDate:` returns a `NSDateComponents`, which then you can grab multiple components.

and then just:

```
NSDate *endDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:openingDay.endTime];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSInteger endDateHour = [self hourFromDate:endDate];
NSInteger endDateMinute = [self minuteFromDate:endDate];

NSInteger todayHour = [self hourFromDate:date];
NSInteger todayMinute = [self minuteFromDate:date];

BOOL hasEndMinutePassed = endDateMinute > todayMinute;
BOOL hasEndHourPassed = endDateHour > todayHour;

if ((hasEndHourPassed) || (endDateHour == todayHour && hasEndMinutePassed)) {
    //Yep, it passed
} else {
    //Nope, it didn't
}
```

I wrote it like this to keep things organized.
You could also write a category:

Header file:

```
@interface NSDate (Components)

- (NSInteger)hour;
- (NSInteger)minutes;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "NSDate+Components.h"

@implementation NSDate (Components)

- (NSInteger)hour {
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:self];
}

- (NSInteger)minute {
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:self];
}
```

You can go a bit further than that and add the comparation logic inside the Category itself:

Adding this to the header:

```
- (BOOL)hourAndMinutesPassedFromDate:(NSDate *)date;
```

and then the implementation:

```
- (BOOL)hourAndMinutesPassedFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    BOOL hasEndMinutePassed = [self minute] > [date minute];
    BOOL hasEndHourPassed = [self hour] > [date hour];

    return ((hasEndHourPassed) || ([self hour] == [date hour] && hasEndMinutePassed));
}
```

Thats it. I didn't test the logic itself (but it should be accurate, i used something like this before), and of course you are free to modify this to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks I will check this in the morning when I am at the computer :)